# Angular nothing to repeat - regex

Tags: angularjs, regex

I want to achieve something like this;

```
0.00
```

- 1 digit before point
- 2 digit after point

And I'm using the regex - `/^([0-9]{1})?+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/` with angular but getting the below error.

```
Invalid regular expression: /^([0-9]{1})?+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/: Nothing to repeat at new RegExp (native)
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Whenever this error occurs, check the character before `*` and `+` quntifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[0-9](?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

Problem is presence of `?` and `+` quantifier after that in your regex.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cL2wT3/1)

Comment: Please stop answering so fast ... We also like to write an answer ... `:-(`

Comment: ha ha :) It was a simple one to spot I guess

Answer (score 1):

`?+` is invalid - the `?` is a quantifier to match 0 or 1 occurrences of the previous token, and `+` matches one or more occurrences - you can't combine the two. (In some regex flavors, a `+` after a quantifier creates a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), but not in JavaScript).

Use

```
/^([0-9])?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

if you plan on having both parts of the regex optional (matching `1` or `1.1` or `.1` or even the empty string).